# If you know what I am, you are certainly not one of me

Tags: riddle

> If you know what I am, you are certainly not one of me.
>
> If you are one of me, you certainly do not know what I am.
>
> I am a living, breathing human being. You can't go far without me.
>
> To know this, is to not be me.

Comment: Any object without consciousness

Comment: Just an observation: the second statement is the contrapositive of the first one, and therefore completely redundant. Unless there's a hidden message or something.

Comment: It would be good if you provide us some hint.

Comment: @Maniraj That's a bit early. No one can answer it because it was put on hold. Moderators: question was amended since it was put on hold, can you consider reopening it?

Comment: (@xhienne Moderators *can*, but are not *needed*, to reopen a question that's on hold.  Users with enough reputation can, and did, vote to reopen this; I gave it the final push.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be

> a newborn baby.

If you know what I am, you are certainly not one of me.

> If you can identify a baby, you're not one.  Because ...

If you are one of me, you certainly do not know what I am.

> ... newborn babies are not aware enough to really know what a baby *is*.

I am a living, breathing human being. You can't go far without me.

> Yup.
>  And you can't leave a newborn alone, you need to bring them with you.

To know this, is to not be me.

> Again, newborns don't have enough cognitive awareness to grasp any of this.

Comment: So, three of the clues are all saying the same thing, and the other one is true only in very particular situations. Seems like a poor puzzle to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost certainly

> A non-sentient being

Explanation:

> Sentient beings are aware of the concept of sentience. Non-sentient beings are not.

Answer (score 0):

You could be a:

> person in a coma

it's just a guess, but it complies with all the conditions

Comment: "You can't go far without me" How it complies with this line?

Comment: my bad, i misread the "without" as a "with". I feel pretty bad now :(

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this while the question was on hold, before it was edited. 
You are

> the cells in a (human) brain.

The explanation is quite similar to that of [Rubio’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/65796/19765#65843).

If you know what I am, you are certainly not one of me.

> An individual brain cell cannot hold a concept,
> like that of a living entity, or an organ in a body.

If you are one of me, you certainly do not know what I am.

> Same as above (contrapositive).

I am a living, breathing human being.

> Oops.  Invalidated by edit.

You can't go far without me.

> It seems like brainless people can function in society,
> but you can’t go far without a brain.

> **Note:** I believe that my answer satisfies the above clue
>   better than [Rubio’s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/65796/19765#65843).

To know this, is to not be me.

> Fifth verse, same as the first.
>
> > OK, actually this one doesn’t work perfectly after the revision either.

> Only an intelligent being (and I use the term loosely :-) )
> can understand a riddle and its answer. 
> So, if you’re reading this, you are not a brain cell.